# Removing certain numbers from batch of filenames

Tags: shell, rename, file-management

I have a batch of files that contain the numbers 21 to 29 in the middle of the file name. As I do not want to remove that number for hundreds of files by hand I tried using Terminal:

```bash
for f in *; 
do for x in {21..29};
rename=`echo "$f" | sed 's/\$x//'`
mv "$f" "$rename"; done;
```

However, nothing happens. If I replace the "$x" with the letter "a" just for fun on a test folder with a few of the files, the first letter "a" is actually removed, but for the numbers it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

I'd appreciate any help very much!
Thank you!

Comment: The file names look like this: "video snap car 23 December.mp4" They are not text files, but video files. There won't be any duplicates even after removing the numbers.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, add the example input there, and also show the expected output. Make sure to mark both input and output as code (use the `{}` button on the editor). That way, we can test our solutions and be sure we are giving you the answer you need. Oh, and please tell us your operating system, if Linux tell us which one, so we know what tools you have available.

Answer (score 1):

Your `sed` command won't work because `$x` isn't expanded when inside single quotes. However you're really using the wrong tools for the job.

If `zsh` is an available shell, I'd suggest switching to that and making use of its `zmv` contributed module and built-in numeric glob range `<m-n>`:

Ex. given

```
 % ls -d -- *.mp4
'video snap 02 car 23 December.mp4'  'video snap car 23 December.mp4'
```

then

```
 % autoload -Uz zmv

 % zmv -n '(*) <21-29> (*.mp4)' '$1 $2'
mv -- 'video snap 02 car 23 December.mp4' 'video snap 02 car December.mp4'
mv -- 'video snap car 23 December.mp4' 'video snap car December.mp4'
```

Remove the `-n` (no-op) when you are happy that the substitution is working correctly.

---

If you cannot use zsh, then since your numeric range is expressible as a simple shell pattern, you could do something like this in bash:

```
$ for f in *2[123456789]*.mp4; do echo mv -n -- "$f" "${f/ 2[123456789]}"; done 
mv -n -- video snap 02 car 23 December.mp4 video snap 02 car December.mp4
mv -n -- video snap car 23 December.mp4 video snap car December.mp4
```

In this case, remove the `echo` to actually rename the files (leave the `-n`, as that protects against overwriting names if they clash).

Comment: Well, to be honest, this totally overwhelmes me. Never heard of shells other than at the beach or the gas station... Just found some code and changed it a bit and did not know that the "sed" had such limits (didn't even know what "sed" would do - just copied and played around a bit. Anyway, thank you very much for your work and thoughts! If there is no other solution that allows me to stay in standard Terminal I will get into that sometime soon...

Comment: The second solution without zsh works like a dream in my limited environment - thank you very much!!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

```bash
for f in *;
do echo "$f" | awk '{gsub("[0-9]{2,}", "", $0); print}'  |xargs -I {} mv "$f" {}
done
```

This code will loop through all your files, pipe the name to **awk**, then awk will replace any occurance of a 2 numbers or more with nothing, and pipe it to the **mv** command ( which is used to rename ).

**xargs** is used to pass the stdin to the correct argument position.

Edit:
As you have supplied new Information about the file name `video snap 02 car 23 December.mp4` then this code should remove the numbers in the second to last field of the name only.

```bash
for f in *;
do echo "$f" | awk '{gsub("[0-9]", "", $(NF-1)); print}'  |sed 's/  / /g'  |xargs -I {} mv "$f" {} ;
done
```

Comment: That looks great. Thanks a lot! There is one problem though. I forgot to mention (my bad!) that some of the files contain other numbers as well, like "video snap 02 car 23 December.mp4". Now the "02" is also removed which would result in several files having the same name. Is there any way to remove only numbers 21 to 29 (or alternatively removing all numbers above 12 will also do), thus keeping the other numbers "intact"?

Comment: If the names of the files are exactly the same as here `video snap 02 car 23 December.mp4`, then this `for f in *; do echo "$f" | awk '{gsub("[0-9]", "", $5); print}'  |sed 's/  / /g'  |xargs -I {} mv "$f" {} ;done` command should work.

Comment: That works on my test folder... Still, some file names are a bit different in structure and there it doesn't work. Running it a second time removes the 4 from ".mp4". :(

Comment: Edit: try the second block of code in the answer. If that didn't work please post a variety of what file names looks like, or one thing that remains constant in all file names, because this is how regex works, it searches for a specific pattern, you can **edit** your post above.